# Automatic Scroll of Images through an XML

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have the following scrip below, where I call some images through an XML, and create a gallery that every 3 seconds it moves to left, passing the pictures automatically. But my images are of different sizes in width, the height is the same.

```
var dados:XML = new XML();
dados.ignoreWhite = true;
dados.load("xml/" + _root.xmlport);
dados.onLoad = function():Void  {
    qtd = this.childNodes[0].childNodes.length;
    _root.qualqtd = this.childNodes[0].childNodes.length;

    for (j = 0; j @= qtd; j++) {
        mcPanels.item_mc.duplicateMovieClip("item_mc" + j,mcPanels.getNextHighestDepth());
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].imagem = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[j].childNodes[0].attributes.imagem;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[j].childNodes[1].attributes.tamanhofoto;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].foto.loadMovie(mcPanels["item_mc" + j].imagem);

        mcPanels["item_mc" + j]._x = j * mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j]._y = 0;
    }
};


var i:Number = 0;
var easing:Number = 0.2;
var clipNum:Number = _root.qualqtd;
var myInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 3000);
var dir:Number = 1;

function moveIt() {

    if (dir == 1) {

        targX = Math.floor(mcPanels._x - 450);
        i++;

        if (i == clipNum) {
            dir = -dir;
        }

    } else if (dir == -1) {

        targX = Math.floor(mcPanels._x + 450);
        i--;

        if (i == 0) {
            dir = -dir;
        }
    }

    onEnterFrame = function () {
        var dx:Number = Math.floor(targX - mcPanels._x);
        mcPanels._x += dx * easing;
        if (Math.abs(dx) @ .5) {
            mcPanels._x = targX;
            delete onEnterFrame;
        }
    };
}
```

How can I make this script get the size of each image and move according to its width?
My XML looks like:

```
menu
    item
        fotoevento imagem='portfolio/15anos/15anos_01.jpg'/
        tamanhofoto tamanhofoto='100'/
    /item
    item
        fotoevento imagem='portfolio/15anos/15anos_02.jpg'/
        tamanhofoto tamanhofoto='50'/
    /item
    item
        fotoevento imagem='portfolio/15anos/15anos_03.jpg'/
        tamanhofoto tamanhofoto='100'/
    /item

/menu
```

Has a value of 450 which is the value that I put to him
move, I know it is there that should change, but do not know how ....

Can someone help me?

**on script where is @ its <**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array to store a reference to each photo holder. In the onLoad function store the clip reference as you create it:

```
//create the imageList
var imageList:Array =[];

dados.onLoad = function():Void  {
    qtd = this.childNodes[0].childNodes.length;
    _root.qualqtd = this.childNodes[0].childNodes.length;

    for (j = 0; j @= qtd; j++) {
        mcPanels.item_mc.duplicateMovieClip("item_mc" + j,mcPanels.getNextHighestDepth());
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].imagem = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[j].childNodes[0].attributes.imagem;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[j].childNodes[1].attributes.tamanhofoto;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].foto.loadMovie(mcPanels["item_mc" + j].imagem);

        mcPanels["item_mc" + j]._x = j * mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j]._y = 0;
        //store a reference to the new foto holder
        imageList.push(mcPanels["item_mc" + j]);
    }
};
```

Then in the moveIt() function, track the current clip and use its width to set the *targX* value:

```
function moveIt() 
{
    var imageWidth:Number  = imageList[i]._width;
    trace("i" +i + "< "+ imageWidth);
    if (dir == 1) 
    {
        targX = Math.floor(mcPanels._x - imageWidth);
        i++;

        if (i == clipNum) 
        {
            dir = -dir;
        }

    } else if (dir == -1) 
    {
        targX = Math.floor(mcPanels._x + imageWidth);
        i--;

        if (i == 0) 
        {
            dir = -dir;
        }
    }
...
}
```

To layout the images with different widths, you need to track how wide each image is as you loop through. I assume *tamanho* is the width (sorry for my poor portuguese!)

```
dados.onLoad = function():Void  {
    qtd = this.childNodes[0].childNodes.length;
    _root.qualqtd = this.childNodes[0].childNodes.length;
    //track the width of the images
    var totalWidth:Number = 0;

    for (j = 0; j @= qtd; j++) {
        mcPanels.item_mc.duplicateMovieClip("item_mc" + j,mcPanels.getNextHighestDepth());
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].imagem = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[j].childNodes[0].attributes.imagem;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[j].childNodes[1].attributes.tamanhofoto;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j].foto.loadMovie(mcPanels["item_mc" + j].imagem);
        //dynamically set the x position based on previous image width
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j]._x = totalWidth;
        mcPanels["item_mc" + j]._y = 0;
        //store a reference to the new foto holder
        imageList.push(mcPanels["item_mc" + j]);

        //i assume you have the width in your xml
        totalWidth += mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho;
    }
};
```

hth

Comment: very nice... i have another question!!.. see the code: 

 mcPanels["item_mc" + j]._x = j * mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho;

this puts a picture in front of the other, but they are of different widths and is not working .. how I can make it right??

Comment: As you have a reference to the clip, you can get the width of each element - so var imageWidth:Number  = imageList[i].foto._width; or var imageWidth:Number  = imageList[i].tamanho._width;  -hth

Comment: lets go: i put this var imageWidth:Number = mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho; and i get the width of all images... but what I do not understand is how to calculate for a position in against another ...

Comment: ok.. i understand this.. and i think u dont understand me, see this link: http://www.alsite.com.br/novo/test/exibe_portifolio.swf the images ar 2 sizes: green and dark red are 100px width, the blue image is 50px width, one is not placed next to each other, and the script that does this is: mcPanels["item_mc" + j]._x = j * mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho; inside FOR loop. How to duplicate the movies right? one next to each other? this is my question now.. ty for your help

Comment: So do you want to find the next x position in order to layout the images next to each other (in dados.onLoad)?

Comment: look the link i have posted: alsite.com.br/novo/test/exibe_portifolio.swf i have disable the move function.. sowing only the movies

Comment: debugging, i have _X of each image:

image_1: _x = 0;
image_2: _x = 64;
image_3: _x = 4136; ==>> oO lol ...

and tamanho = size

Comment: The layout code starts with at totalWidth of 0. This places the first image at x=0. The loop then adds the tamanho to the totalWidth, so the second image has a x position equal to the width of the first image, the third image has an x position equal to the width of clips 1 and 2, etc

Comment: so what i'm doing wrong?. my first image has 100px width, second 50px, and third 100px.. i realy dont know what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: if i trace(totalWidth) my result its: 0100 , 010050, 010050100.. the number are not adding...

Comment: the value for tamanho needs to be a number where is is currently being treated as a string.Try mcPanels["item_mc" + j].tamanho = Number (this.childNodes[0].childNodes[j].childNodes[1].attributes.tamanhofoto);

Comment: WOW!!!! works!!!!!! Thank you!! Thank you!! Thank you!! Thank you!!.. you save my day, (and my neck!) hehehe..